# Laravel prefix route and json file url is not matching

Tags: json, laravel, routes, prefix

I am trying Laravel 6 prefix. My problem is when I access from my home page `http://localhost:8000/` to my sidebar `http://localhost:8000/project/add-project` it is file but when I try my sidebar `http://localhost:8000/project/add-project` to my sidebar `http://localhost:8000/project/add-project` or other sidebar it always adds an extra project word like this: `http://localhost:8000/project/project/add-project`

My route:

```
Route::prefix('project')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/add-project', 'ProjectsController@addProject')->name('projects-add-project');
    Route::post('/add-project', 'ProjectsController@processAddProject')->name('projects-add-project');
    Route::get('/active-project-list', 'ProjectsController@activeProjectList')->name('active-project-list');

});
```

My json file:

```
{"menu": [
    {"url":"/", "name":"Dashboard", "slug":"dashboard", "badgeClass": "badge badge-warning badge-pill float-right mr-2", "icon":"feather icon-home"},
    {"url":"","navheader":"Projects","icon":""},
        {"url":"", "name":"Project", "icon":"feather icon-layers",
          "submenu": [
            {"url":"project/add-project", "name":"Add Project", "icon":"feather icon-plus-circle", "i18n":"nav.add_project"},
            {"url":"project/active-project-list" , "name":"Active Projects", "icon":"feather icon-list", "i18n":"nav.active_projects"},
            {"url":"#", "name":"Hold Projects", "icon":"feather icon-list", "i18n":"nav.hold_projects"},
            {"url":"#", "name":"Completed Projects", "icon":"feather icon-list", "i18n":"nav.completed_projects"},
            {"url":"#", "name":"Cancelled Projects", "icon":"feather icon-list", "i18n":"nav.cancelled_projects"},
            {"url":"#", "name":"All Projects List", "icon":"feather icon-list", "i18n":"nav.all_projects_list"}
          ]
        }
]}
```

My submenu class:

```
<ul class="menu-content">
    @foreach($menu as $submenu)
        <?php
            $submenuTranslation = "";
            if(isset($menu->i18n)){
                $submenuTranslation = $menu->i18n;
            }
        ?>
        <li class="{{ (request()->is($submenu->url)) ? 'active' : '' }}">
            <a href="{{ $submenu->url }}">
                <i class="{{ isset($submenu->icon) ? $submenu->icon : "" }}"></i>
                <span class="menu-title" data-i18n="{{ $submenuTranslation }}">{{ $submenu->name }}</span>
            </a>
            @if (isset($submenu->submenu))
                @include('panels/submenu', ['menu' => $submenu->submenu])
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Is there any way to fix it, can I use route instead of url? If I can how can I do that?

Comment: Add a slash to the urls: `{"url":"/project/add-project"` and `{"url":"/project/active-project-list"`

Comment: I made an answer with "some" explanation you might want to accept so this question can be marked as resolved. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using relative urls in your links. Which doesn't pose a problem when you are not in any subfolder:

When on `http://localhost` a link `<a href="project/add-project">..</a>` will link to the *relative* location `http://localhost/project/add-project`.

If you however already are in a subfolder `http://localhost/project/`, a link `<a href="project/add-project">..</a>` will link to the *relative* location `http://localhost/project/project/add-project`.

You can overcome this by prepending your urls with a slash `/`, telling your browser to go to the uppermost location on the site first: being on `http://localhost/project` a link `<a href="/project/add-project">..</a>` (notice the `/`) will link to the uppermost location `http://localhost` first, then going to `project/add-project`, resulting in `http://localhost/project/add-project`.

#### tl;dr:

In your json file, prepend your urls with a slash to make them absolute:

```
{"url":"/project/add-project" ..
{"url":"/project/active-project-list" ..
```